# Referring to local variables in Concourse credentials file

Tags: concourse, concourse-pipeline

I have the following credentials.yml file :

```yaml
test: 123
test2: ((test))
```

When I upload a pipeline, feeding it with the credentials file , whenever test2 variable is used it is not interpolated and I'm getting a `"undefined vars : test"` error in Concourse.

Is it even possible to refer to another variable in the very same yaml or do you have to always refer to variables in a configured credentials manager (e.g. Vault) ?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it using anchors and aliases . Sadly keys containing dots or hyphens do not work at all.

e.g. :

```yaml
test: &test 123
test2: *test
```